# iproute2: Database /etc/iproute2/rt_tables is corrupted

Tags: iproute2

I'm setting up two IP addresses on one eth and one IP address on a second NIC using iproute2.  There are some really good articles [here](https://kindlund.wordpress.com/2007/11/19/configuring-multiple-default-routes-in-linux/) and [here](http://www.generationip.com/documentation/network-documentation/93-howto-setup-multiple-default-gateway-on-linux) which explain well how to do that.

However, checking the rules with *ip rule show*, returns in error with:

*Database /etc/iproute2/rt_tables is corrupted at ip route add 192.168.15.0 dev eth0 src 192.168.15.190 table mgmtsecond*

I've been googling for hours but not much on this error.  I've checked the syntax with the official docs.  Looks fine.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!!

**/etc/iproute2/rt_tables**

```
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# Mgmt Alias and Mon Ports
#
1  mgmtsecond
2  monport

# Management Port Second Instance
# Main#2 def is 192.168.15.1

ip route add 192.168.15.0/24 dev eth0 src 192.168.15.190 table mgmtsecond
ip route add default via 192.168.15.1 dev eth0 table mgmtsecond

# Monitor Port. Default 192.168.16.1

ip route add 192.168.16.0/24 dev eth1 src 192.168.16.190 table monport
ip route add default via 192.168.16.1 dev eth1 table monport

ip rule add from 10192.168.15.0/24 table mgmtsecond
ip rule add to 192.168.15.0/24 table mgmtsecond
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not add the commands `ip route add` and `ip rule add` to this file `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`. The file format is as follows:

```
table_id    table_name
```

example:

```
255     local
```

The error message is clear about the error location:

> Database /etc/iproute2/rt_tables is corrupted at ip route add
>   192.168.15.0 dev eth0 src 192.168.15.190 table mgmtsecond

Routes and rules should be added manually or to some other script to be invoked when needed. For example, you can add them to `/etc/rc.local` script which is invoked at end of startup process if want so.